# How to show the Legends of chars into two line?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, charts

I have to show the legends in multiple lines. Legend will have a fixed width. I have tried to play with legends settings but it not working.

```
    let l = chartView.legend
    l.horizontalAlignment = .center
    l.verticalAlignment = .bottom
    l.orientation = .horizontal
    l.drawInside = false
    l.xEntrySpace = 5
    l.yEntrySpace = 2
    l.yOffset = 5
    l.xOffset = 20
```

[image]

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: @RakeshaShastriI have tried with legends settings